# Is there a more efficient way to instantiate a COM object from PHP running in IIS?

Tags: php, .net, iis, com

I'm running a web app based around pages loaded by `php-cgi.exe` in IIS.

I can create a .NET library exposed to COM, generate a TLB and register it:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\TlbExp.exe" RomCom.dll
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe /u RomCom.dll
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe /codebase RomCom.dll /tlb:RomCom.tlb
```

...and access the class's members from PHP thusly:

```
$commie = new COM("RomCom.LettersClass");
print_r($commie->X);
```

However, when instantiated in this way, the library containing the COM object takes some time to load within each PHP execution -- I can tell by wrapping that line in `microtime()` that this takes about 0.2 seconds On My Machine™. Since subsequent instantiations *within* each PHP execution are much less costly, I assume that this cost is either due to the lookup of the COM library, or to some stuff that happens when the library is loaded into the PHP environment

**Is there any way to configure the PHP environment, or possibly IIS, to speed up the (repeated) loading of this COM object?**

Bonus question: am I asking the right question, or is there a better way to call into .NET code from PHP? I've read about the `NetPhp` library, but my understanding is that it uses the `COM` class under the hood and so would be subject to the same performance penalty.

Comment: "COM objects"? In 2017? Seriously?

Comment: Yeah, I know. Feel free to respond to bonus question.

Answer (score 1):

200ms seems quite high for loading the CLR, you should also consider doing some CPU profiling to determine what is taking so long.  You may see considerable benefit from ngen'ing your assembly, or by lazy-initializing some expensive object.  You won't know unless you look.  You could also increase your recycling time, to minimize the number of loads.

This is a good candidate for serviced components or an out-of-process server.  In either case, you end up with the .Net COM Server running in a different process that lasts beyond the lifetime of the calling `php-cgi` process.

[Serviced Components in VB.NET](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3955/Serviced-Components-in-VB-NET) has a good overview, and can be readily translated to C#.  There is also [a sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty17dz7h(VS.80).aspx) in .Net 2 on MSDN.  In both cases, you can just ignore the transactional stuff.

The more modern route would be to have a local WCF or MVC web service.  You should get roughly equivelent performance regardless of whether you go with COM or web services, it really depends upon what you are most comfortable developing and troubleshooting.